# What is the difference between filter(_:).first and first(where:)?

Tags: arrays, swift, big-o

Please consider the following strings array:

```
let strings = ["str1", "str2", "str10", "str20"]
```

Let's assume that what required is to get the first element (String) which contains 5 characters, I could get it by using [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905694-filter) as follows:

```
let filterString = strings.filter { $0.count == 5 }.first
print(filterString!) // str10
```

but after reviewing the [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) method, I recognized that I will be able to get the same output:

```
let firstWhereString = strings.first(where: { $0.count == 5 })
print(firstWhereString!) // str10
```

So what is the benefit of using one instead of the other? is it only about that the `filter(_:)` returns a sequence and the `first(where:)` returns a single element?

**Update:**

I noticed that the filter(_:) took *5 times* to do such a process, while first(where:) took *4 times*:

[image]

Comment: `first` could be written to short cut, so it only evaluates the condition for enough elements to find the first that matches, whereas the `filter` has to evaluate it for every element.

Comment: "*is it only about that the filter(_:) returns a sequence and the first(where:) returns a single element?*" isn't that enough?

Comment: Change the closure to `{ print("Testing:", $0) ; return $0.count == 5 }` and you'll see the difference. – Another option is `strings.lazy.filter(predicate).first`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct in observing that [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905694-filter) returns *all* elements that satisfy a predicate and that [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) returns the *first* element that satisfy a predicate.

So, that leaves us with the more interesting question of what the difference is between `elements.filter(predicate).first` and 
`elements.first(where: predicate)`.

As you've already noticed they both end up with the same result. The difference is in their "evaluation strategy". Calling:

```
elements.filter(predicate).first
```

will "eagerly" check the predicate against all elements to filter the full list of elements, and then pick the first element from the filterer list. By comparison, calling:

```
elements.first(where: predicate)
```

will "lazily" check the predicate against the elements until it finds one that satisfies the predicate, and then return that element.

As a third alternative, you can explicitly use "a view onto [the list] that provides lazy implementations of normally eager operations, such as `map` and `filter`":

```
elements.lazy.filter(predicate).first
```

This changes the evaluation strategy to be "lazy". In fact, it's so lazy that just calling `elements.lazy.filter(predicate)` won't check the predicate against *any* elements. Only when the `first` element is "eagerly" evaluated on this lazy view will it evaluate enough elements to return one result.

---

Separately from any technical differences between these alternatives, I'd say that you should use the one that most clearly describes your intentions. If you're looking for the first element that matches a criteria/predicate then `first(where:)` communicates that *intent* best.

Comment: Thanks for providing a useful answer. I would really need to know more about how to deal with `lazy` :)

Comment: Agreed, `lazy` is an interesting topic.

Answer (score 2):

I believe we should start from considering each method separately and their purpose.

`filter(_:)` is not purposefully designed to prepare us to obtain `first` element. It is about filtering and that's it. It merely returns us a sequence. `first` can be used after `filter`, but that's just an instance of usage, a possible case. `first` is called for a collection and if we want, of course we are free to use it directly after `filter`.

But `first(where:)` was *designed* to `filter and return` a single element and is evidently the go-to approach to accomplish that kind of a task. That said, it is easy to presume that it's also preferred from performance perspective. As mentioned, we `filter` entire sequence, but with `first(where:)` we only process the portion of a sequence until condition is met.

Comment: "filter returns a sequence" is technically correct, but in many cases that sequence is an *array.* With `lazy` that eager operation can be replaced by a lazy one.