# How to find first non-zero element of an Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Is there a way to grab the first non-zero element from an array of numbers?

I have an Array with many zeros at the beginning and I need only the first item that is not a zero.

For example:

```
let array = [0,0,0,0,25,53,21,77]
```

based on the above, the result should be 25.

What is the good way to achieve it?

Comment: `let idx = myArray.indexOf({$0 != 0})`
`let item = myArray[idx]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get it like this:

```
let array = [0,0,0,0,25,53,21,77]

let firstNonZero = array.first { element -> Bool in
    return element != 0
}
```

Or as a shorter version:

```
let firstNonZero = array.first(where: { $0 != 0 })
```

Note that `firstNonZero` would be an *optional* Int, so in case of `array` contains only zeros, `firstNonZero` would be `nil`.

---

***Aside bar note***: If you were wondering why to use `first(where:)` instead of `filter(_:).first`, you could check this question:

[What is the difference between filter(_:).first and first(where:)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808889/what-is-the-difference-between-filter-first-and-firstwhere)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Very interesting. I didn't know this