# What is the time complexity of first-where?

Tags: swift, time-complexity, big-o

For clarification, [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) method keeps iterating through the sequence until it finds the satisfied element and returns it.

Based on that I would assume that it is *not* [`O(n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O(n)) (linear time) because at some point it doesn't has to iterate through the whole sequence until its end.

<sub>You could check: [What is the difference between filter(_:).first and first(where:)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808889/what-is-the-difference-between-filter-first-and-firstwhere)</sub>

I'm not sure if it could be something relates to `O(log n)`, AFAIK it has something to do with splitting into halves...

It would be great if someone could describe how we can determine the time complexity for such a process.

Comment: The “worst case” is still O(N) because it has to traverse the entire array if no matching element is found. – A *binary search* has O(log N) complexity, is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: Go one up the page hierarchy and you see " **Array. 
   An ordered, random-access collection.** ". How would you search that in `O(log N)`?

Comment: You can also inspect the source code: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L971.

Comment: On average you'll only have to check 1/2 of the values, so you'd think it would be O(1/2 N).  But O() notation ignores constants.  O(N) means it grows linearly as the number of elements grows.  For 10, you'd check 5 on average, for 100, you'd check 50, for 1000, you'd check 500 on average.  Connect (10,5), (100,50), (1000, 500).  That's a straight line.

Comment: @MartinR so should be *always* calculated based on its worst case? Which means it is O(n)?

Comment: One usually distinguishes between "worst case" and "average case". For example, quicksort has an average time of O(n log n), but a worst case of O(n^2). – Here it makes no difference. As vacawama said, O(n) and O(n/2) is considered identical from the "big-O" perspective.

Comment: You'll find all the analysis here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search.

Comment: @vacawama That's a full fledged answer right there. Submit it, and reap the internet points!

Comment: @MartinR Woah, what's with that strange use of `forEach`? Since you can't make a parent scope return from within a closure scope, it forces the use of `throw StopIteration._stop`. Wouldn't that code be much simpler with a `for` loop, and a simple `return`?

Comment: @Alexander Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/159535/35991 where Hamish elaborates on that.

Comment: @MartinR Classic Hamish, wicked answer. Could you explain what they mean by "escapes" in the context of "the type itself may have a more optimal implementation of forEach since it can guarantee nothing escapes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On average you'll only have to check 1/2 of the values, so you'd think `first(where:)` would be `O(1/2 N)`. But `O()` notation ignores constants. `O(N)` means it grows linearly as the number of elements grows. For `10` items, you'd check `5` on average, for `100`, you'd check `50`, for `1000`, you'd check `500` on average. Connect the points `(10,5)`, `(100,50)`, `(1000, 500)`. That's a straight line.

Comment: Thanks. So we are *always* care about the worst case to measure it, right? If it's correct, then I could assume that complexity time for finding an element using `first-where` and `filter.first` (the case for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808889/what-is-the-difference-between-filter-first-and-firstwhere) are the same, which is O(n). Please advice.

Comment: Yes, we do consider the worst case scenario when deciding complexity. Yes, both `first-where` and `filter.first` are `O(n)`. Remember that big-O notation ignores constants, so you can’t rely on just complexity to compare what a user’s experience will be with an algorithm, because humans care very much about constants. On average, `first-where` will be twice as fast as `filter.first` which always has to look at every element.

Answer (score 4):

We are usually interested in the **worst case** running time of a program. Based on that, it should be `O(n)` as the worst case is when it iterates through all the elements.

Comment: Thanks. So we are *always* care about the worst case to measure it, right? If it's correct, then I could assume that complexity time for finding an element using `first-where` and `filter.first` (the case for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808889/what-is-the-difference-between-filter-first-and-firstwhere) are the same, which is O(n). Please advice.

Comment: Yeah. The complexity of both is O(n). Their evaluation strategy is different through. But that doesn't mean they take the same time to run. `first-where` would be faster than `filter.first`. You can read more on algorithmic complexity [here.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html)